# Basic authentication once time for all

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I developped a spring-boot application. When I need to do REST requests (POST, PUT...) I use every time basic authentication like that

```
HttpEntity<PostJql> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<PostJql>(post, jiraUtils.getHeader());
        ResponseEntity<IssueDataWrapper> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlJiraResponse, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, IssueDataWrapper.class);
```

Is there another way to do basic authentication once time in the application and then use RestTemplate or httpPost {Put/Delete...} without basic authentication ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Configure your `RestTemplate` with a `ClientHttpRequestFactory` that does what you need.

You can just set it in the constructor:

```
  restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

... or you can make all of these things beans and let Spring wire it.

You could extend `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`, overriding `createRequest()`:

```
 public class BasicAuthSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory 
        extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

     @Override
     public HttpClientRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) {
         HttpClientRequest request = super.createRequest(uri, httpMethod);
         HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
         headers.add(... your auth header ...);
         return request;
     }
 }
```

... or you could bring in Apache HttpComponents as a dependency and use an `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, and configure the underlying Apache `HttpClient` to do the authentication you need. Apache [documents this in detail](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html), but to get you started:

```
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = 
         new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
```

In my experience it's worth bringing in Apache HttpComponents if you can -- it is more reliable and configurable than the `HttpUrlConnection` based HTTP client that `RestTemplate` otherwise uses by default. When your requirements broaden to things like other authentication methods, timeouts, retry strategies etc., you'll be glad you have an `HttpClient` to configure.